# How to scale service layer methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns

We are at the design stage of developing an application.

We decided to implement DDD oriented design.

Our application has a service layer.

Each method in the service has its own task.

**Sample**

let's consider a user service.

This method gets all users

```
public User GetAll()
{
   //codes
}
```

Now if I want to sort all users by name.

**Option-1**

Use another method

```
public User GetAllAndOrderByAsc()
```

Or

```
public User GetAllAndOrderByDesc()
```

Different method for each different situation.

it doesn't look good at all

**Option-2**

Continue query at Api or Application level

```
public IQueryable<User> GetAll()
{
    //codes
}
```

Api or Application Level

```
var users = from u in _userService.GetAll()
            select u;

switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "name_desc":
        users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Name);
        break;
    case "name_asc":
        users = students.OrderBy(u => u.Name);
        break;
    default:
        users = students.OrderBy(u => u.Name);
        break;
}
```

The options that come to my mind are limited to these.

am I making a mistake somewhere or couldn't grasp the logic. would you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're not crazy: this is a common problem, and the options you've listed are legitimate, each with pros and cons, and commonly used in practice.

Depending on the context of your app, it's theoretically possible to expose the `IQueryable<>` all the way to the presentation layer (using OData if you're running a web service, e.g.). But I find that it's wiser to exercise a little more control over the API to avoid the possibility of having someone hit the endpoint with a request that basically downloads your entire database.

In your service layer, you want to think about what use cases you really expect people to use.

- It's rare for someone to literally need to see all the users: that might only happen when it's part of an export process, and rather than returning a collection you might want to return an `IObservable` that pushes values out as they emerge in a stream from the database.
- More often, you're going to want to get a page of users at a time to show in the UI. This will probably need to have sorting and searching applied to it as well.
- You'll almost certainly want a way to get one user whose ID you already know (maybe one that was picked from the paged list).
- You might also expect to need to query based on specific criteria. Maybe people should typically only see "Active" users. Maybe they should be thinking in terms of specific groupings of users.

In my experience, it has worked well to make my Service layer represent these Domain-level assumptions about how the application should think about things, and write interfaces that support the use cases you actually want to support, even if that means you often find yourself adding new Service methods to support new features. For example:

```
Task<IReadOnlyCollection<User>> GetPageOfActiveUsersAsync(
    PagingOptions pagingOptions, 
    SortOptions sortOptions, 
    string searchTerm, 
    IReadOnlyCollection<int> organizationIds);
Task<User> GetActiveUserByUsernameAsync(string username);
Task<User> GetActiveUserByIdAsync(int userId);
IObservable<User> GetAllUsersForAuditExport();
```

The project I currently work on uses a class like this:

```
public class SortSettings
{
    public string SortField { get; set; }
    public SortDirection SortDirection { get; set; } = SortDirection.Asc;
}
```

Then, depending on what we're querying, we may use reflection, a `switch` statement, or some other mechanism to pick a SortExpression (`Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>`), and then apply the sort like this:

```
query = sortOptions.SortDirection == SortDirection.Asc 
    ? query.OrderBy(sortExpression)
    : query.OrderByDescending(sortExpression);
```

That logic is fairly easy to extract out into a separate method if you find you're using it in a lot of places.

You'll likely find other common features like Searching and Paging require a similar approach.